# Capturing data with Invoke-WebRequest from a continuously updating webpage

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a website which updates continuously with SNMP alert trap and i want to capture the data with powershell  Invoke-WebRequest command. Since the table is updating all the time.. i am unable to complete the request.
Is there any other way to capture the data

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri_West1 -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Without extra information about how the page updates this data it's very hard to give you advise. As a tip to find out how the page does this: use a webdebugger like Fiddler (or the browser debugging tools and then the network tab) to see which calls are made to update this data. A lot of pages actually make API calls to a REST API making it very easy to update this. If the page is streaming the data continiously causing the request to "hang" it's a lot harder to do though

Comment: @bluuf: Apologies for late reply. We have managed to fix this by filtering unwanted SNMP trap. Much appreciate your response with this.